# How can I obtain the details of Kubernetes events that occurred 15 days ago, including deployment information?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I want see aws eks cluster using Kubernetes events pod that occurred 15 days ago, including deployment information?

How to check this?

Comment: https://github.com/resmoio/kubernetes-event-exporter. See also https://www.cncf.io/blog/2021/12/21/extracting-value-from-the-kubernetes-events-feed/